# If a new duplicate question is better written than the first, which one to keep?

Tags: discussion

I put up this question:
[Do some Christian churches worship the saints and/or angels?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15785/why-worship-saints-mary-angels)

And it was closed as duplicate of https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9719/catholicism-and-christianity

However, as other users suggested, it is written better and more explicit than the first.

This will allow others looking for this question to find it easier and faster.
Thus, should it be closed? Or maybe the original re-edited?

However, I feel the answers are also better written so I just wanted to hear an oppinion on this.

This is just an example since the first one was closed as not constructive, but I'm sure other cases will appear.

Thanks.

Comment: I strongly believe that anyone who has a good enough memory to realize it's a duplicate should take the trouble to add the URL to the original discussion. It clutters up the discussion list with all these Closed: Duplicate questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We should pick the better of duplicates and make hat the parent. If the two questions are close enough to be merged then the answers from the old question should be moved.

However, I don't see these as duplicates, the original question is closed and I see no reason to close the new question as a duplicate of an old closed question. Neither do I see particular reason to reopen the old question just to add a duplicate link (which is what I'd have to do). An answer from the other question fits, and probably fits it better than it does the current state of the other question. (also the title on that other one is kind of garbage).

Secondly, while your question has attracted votes to close, it is not closed yet. The answers are good so far and I don't see any reason that with the edit it shouldn't stay open. Don't fret about close votes, start worrying when a question is actually closed. It takes 5 close votes from normal users though just one from a moderator) to close a question. There is a reason for this, so that we get a multitude of opinions on a question and so that lots of people have an opportunity to see it and improve it before it gets closed.